# Using .vue compoent in vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

i'm new in laravel with vue.js,
i just try created my vue.js component using in modules,
my laravel, blade look like this.

```
< vue-dashboard> </ vue-dashboard>
```

in my Dashboard.vue, i want to add autocomplete component that i got from [here](https://github.com/fareez-ahamed/autocomplete-vuejs2/blob/master/src/components/Autocomplete.vue)

so in my Dashboard.vue look like this.

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">PIC</label>
<autocomplete :suggestions="cities" :selection.sync="form.pic_name"></autocomplete>
</div>
```

but before this can render vue-dashboard it got error like this:

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/components/Autocomplete.Vue 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <template>
|     <div style="position:relative" v-bind:class="{'open':openSuggestion}">
|         <input class="form-control" type="text" :value="value" @input="updateValue($event.target.value)"
 @ ./resources/js/components/aset/Manager.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--4-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./resources/js/components/aset/Manager.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&) 137:0-47 142:18-30
 @ ./resources/js/components/aset/Manager.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./resources/js/components/aset/Manager.vue
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! path /var/www/html
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/sail/.npm/_logs/2021-01-02T13_05_12_418Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! path /var/www/html
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c npm run development
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/sail/.npm/_logs/2021-01-02T13_05_12_435Z-debug.log
```

so where is my wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Dashboard.vue should look like:

```
<template>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">PIC</label>
    <autocomplete :suggestions="cities" :selection.sync="form.pic_name"></autocomplete>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   name: 'vue-dashboard'
   ...
}
</script>

<style>
...
</style>
```

You can find doc [here](https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html).